# Confused on Access First() to SQL, I tried using an alternate but that is giving me the wrong data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access

I need to get the first item description for each group of unit upc,i read a lot of forms but confused on how to approach this, plz help.

**Access Query**

```
SELECT ItemDescLookups.[Unit UPC Base Item], First(ItemDescLookups.[Item Description]) AS [Item Description]
FROM ItemDescLookups
GROUP BY ItemDescLookups.[Unit UPC Base Item];
```

**THE SQL I CREATED**

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT MIN(dbo.ItemDescLookups.[Item Description]) AS ItemDescription,
           dbo.[Overpack Percentages].[Unit UPC Base Item]
FROM dbo.[Overpack Percentages] LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemDescLookups ON dbo.[Overpack Percentages].[Unit UPC Base Item] = dbo.ItemDescLookups.[Unit UPC Base Item]
GROUP BY dbo.[Overpack Percentages].[Unit UPC Base Item]
ORDER BY dbo.[Overpack Percentages].[Unit UPC Base Item]
```

Original Data

```
Unit UPC Base Item, Item Description    
0001                1LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES    
0001                454 g ASSTD CHOCOLATES  
0001                1LB ASST CHOC DISPLAYER 
0001                1LB ASST HALF PALLET    
0001                1LB ASST CHOC PALLET    
0001                1LB ASST CHOC DISPLR    
0001                1 LB ASSORTED CHOCOLATES    
0001                1LB WRAPPED ASSTD CHOCOLATES    
0001                1 LB ASST. CHOC. POLE PACK  
0001                454 g ASST CHOC DISPLR  
0001                1lb PROMO AC W/FREE 2oz TRL BX  
0001                1 LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES   
0001                1LB ASSTD CHOCO W/FLAG WRAP 
0001                1lb ASSTD CHOC SILVER LABEL 
0001                1 LB ASST CHOC DISPLAYER    
0001                1lb ASSTD CHOC GOLD LABEL   
0001                1LB ASST PALLET 
0001                60-RSC 1# AC (8630) POLE DSP    
0001                12 OZ ASSTD CHOCOLATES  
0002                2LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES    
0002                908 g ASSTD CHOCOLATES  
0002                2LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES FLOOR  
0002                2 LB ASSORTED CHOCOLATES    
0002                2LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES HALF PLT   
0002                2# ASSORTED PALLET PACK 
0002                2LB SAMPLER AST CHOC    
0002                2LB ASSTD CHOC W/FLAG WRAP  
0003                3LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES    
0003                3 LB Asstd Chocolates   
0003                3lb Assorted Chocolates 
0003                3lb Asstd Chocolates  Wrapped   
0005                5LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES    
0005                5 LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES   
0005                2270 g ASSTD CHOCOLATES
```

Expected Result

```
Unit UPC Base Item, Item Description
0001                1LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES
0002                2LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES
0003                3LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES
0005                5LB ASSTD CHOCOLATES
```

The Result I got from SQL

```
Unit UPC Item           Item Description
    0001                1 LB ASSORTED CHOCOLATES    
    0002                2 LB ASSORTED CHOCOLATES    
    0003                3 LB Asstd Chocolates   
    0005                2270 g ASSTD CHOCOLATES
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replicating the MS Access "First" function in SQL Server Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916994/replicating-the-ms-access-first-function-in-sql-server-query)

Comment: @Beth this is not a duplicate of  Replicating the MS Access "First" function in SQL Server Query because he is using count in the query and he is taking the value that has the highest value of the count. i just need the first record of the group and count does me no good. Just because both our questions relate to First function doesn't mean they are duplicates.

Comment: how do you define 'first'?  alphabetically by item description?  then the SQL results are correct because 2270 < 5lb.  You have to explicitly define a sequence to determine which row is 'first.'  It's not the sequence in which the row was inserted into the table.

Comment: @Beth i think for each different Unit UPC we need to select top 1, i am just having issue with the logic here, some say use CTE, some say the min() does this, some use the Row_number and then select the max from that. To be honest i am just not sure how to go about it. they have something called FIRST_VALUE that does this in Sql 2012 but too bad we are just using Sql 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following in both Access and SQL server:

```
SELECT Data1.Unit, 
       (select top 1 z.[Item Description] from data1 as z 
    where z.Unit = data1.Unit ORDER BY z.Unit, z.ID) AS myfirst
FROM Data1
GROUP BY Data1.Unit;
```

Because there are no aggurates, then we don't have to include the description in the group by clause.

Keep in mind that above assumes a PK value of ID  that been added to the table. This PK value is important, since the select top 1 MUST ONLY return one row else the query will fail. So the magic sauce here is including two columns in the order by clause to ensure that ONLY one row meets the top 1 criteria.

Comment: appreciate the help, if i hadn't seen your answer i was going to create a CTE then implement that in a view, if that hadn't work i would have created a stored procedure you have saved me time and effort :)